# I'm questioning my question questionability

Tags: discussion, support

can someone explain how is this question not a question?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150421/how-to-make-webpages-concise

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple issues with your post (I won't call it a question because it isn't one, either semantically or structurally).

First, you have made no effort to understand how the wiki works and to invest even a minimal amount of effort in presenting your issue in a way that conforms to the site's [guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Your post is non-specific to the point of being unintelligble; you haven't even bothered to type it in English, preferring some pidgin txtspeak/pseudo programming patois that is made even more nonsensical by the random application of code formatting.

Second, even if the post contained a question, and that question was intelligble (and, to recap, neither criteria were even remotely close to being met), it has—assumimg that the title is some indication as to what you were attempting to ask—absolutely *nothing* to do with Unix and Linux and would probably only be suitable on the English Language and Usage site where, for the reasons stated above, it would also get closed promptly.

Finally, I can only suggest that should you wish to continue to participate in the community, you recognise that typically when expecting something from a community (help, answers and the like) you make some small effort to bring something to the table yourself. In this case, pretty much all we ask is that you take the time to read the guidance and to format your question in a way that makes it easy for people to respond and *adds some value to the site.*

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that such an extension would be magic, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Unix/Linux

Comment: can someone explain why "magic"

Comment: where should i move the question?